# JQuery Ajax form submit along with usual submit on the same form in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, dmi

Do Struts tags `<s:submit>` and  `<sj:submit>` work on same form? I have already Struts buttons `<s:submit>`, but now I have added `<sj:submit>`.

So, [Struts 2 jQuery plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=119537#content/view/119537) button is working good, but Struts `<s:submit>` is not working.

```jsp
<head>
<sj:head/>
</head>
<s:form id="myForm" action="part!list">
   <s:submit  action="part" method="list" />
</s:form>
<sj:submit targets="result" formId="myform"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`<s:submit>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/submit-tag.html) works with the form if it's inside the body of the [`<s:form>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/form-tag.html) or `<form>` tag. To make it work properly use the `action` attribute to map the form to the action. You could also use [`<s:url>`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/url-tag.html) to build the url used in the `action` attribute of the form that correctly builds url even with parameters. But if you map the action in the `<s:submit>` tag then you have to use only one attribute `action` or `method`. These are special parameters used by the action mapper. In the first case form `action` will be overridden, in the second case the action method overridden. It means that the attributes `action` and `method` in the `<submit>` tag only used to override the default form action mapping. It's rarely used, requires [DMI](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation), if you have multiple buttons that have different methods consider to use the `method` attribute to override the form action mapping.

**EDIT:**

**Example:**

```xml
<head>
   <sj:head/>
</head>
<s:url var="myUrl" action="part" method="list"/>
<s:form id="myForm" action="%{#myUrl}" method="POST">
   <s:submit  action="part2" />
   <s:submit  method="list2" />
   <s:submit />
</s:form>

<sj:submit targets="result" formId="myForm"/>
```

the above `<s:submit>` in the first case use actin named `part2` to submit to,
the second action name `part` and method `list2`,
the third is default action name `part` and method `list`
Ajax calls like the third case.

If your action is mapped on the method `list`, then you could simplify the url via

```xml
<s:url var="myUrl" action="part"/>
```

Comment: Okay , what about <sj:submit> outside form..<head>
<sj:head/>
</head>
<s:form id="myForm" action="part!list">
   <s:submit  action="part" method="list" />
</s:form>
<sj:submit targets="result" formId="myform"

Comment: Could you please give me small example for method overridden using url.

Comment: `sj:submit` works slightly different than s:submit and has `formId` attribute, so it can find the form which is submitting and serialize it to set `formData` in Ajax post.

Comment: @user2543737 I have updated the answer, and if you produce urls like `action!method` it could use the `method` other than mapped to the `action`. Notice if action is not mapped to the method then it's treated `execute` method is mapped instead.