# Struts <s:submit> and Struts-jquery <sj:submit> will not work in same form Part 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, struts2, struts2-jquery

This is in reference to question [JQuery Ajax form submit along with usual submit on the same form in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17454151/573032).

I am also trying to get a regular Struts 2 `<s:submit>` and a Struts 2 jQuery `<sj:submit>` to work on the same page.

I followed the answer that Roman C gave, but it still doesn't work.

My setup for the form looks like this:

```jsp
<head>
    <sj:head/>
</head>
<s:form id="dataForm" action="updateData" method="POST">
    <s:hidden name="updatedDate" />
    <s:submit id="nonAjaxSubmit" name="updateDataSubmit" value="Update and Close"/>
</s:form>
<sj:submit formIds="dataForm" name="updateDataAjaxSubmit" value="Update" targets="result"/>
```

I have the `<s:submit>` inside the form as Roman C specified.

The Ajax Submit `<sj:submit>` button works, but the regular submit `<s:submit>` button that's inside the form doesn't work.

I'm not trying to override the action method to use like the other questioner, I'm just trying to get the `<s:submit>` to work.

I need the `<s:submit>` to trigger the action and do the redirect as specified by the action in the `struts.xml` file.  And I need the `<sj:submit>` to trigger the same action asynchronously while leaving the loaded page in the browser alone.

If anyone has an idea of what I might need to do to get it to work, that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18944973/1700321?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin overrides a `submit` event on the form then you should try `click` event and submit the form using javascript `submit()`.

For example:

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("nonAjaxSubmit").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     this.form.submit();
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Both Roman C's answer and the solution in question [18944973](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944973/jquery-and-default-struts-2-submit-buttons-in-one-form) work.  Thanks guys.